# unix pass > press ENTER yields `^M` when typing

Tags: mutt, password-store

Whilst trying to learn `pass` password manager I noticed that I cannot press Enter key. This also happens when I try to use muttwizard for configuring mutt/neomutt, eg. during password I cannot press enter so I can't finish the configuration..

When I press enter, then it prints `^M`. Does anyone here know why this is? This only happens for these two programs so far.

I am also not sure what more info to bring so please tell me if you need to know something more about my system.

Comment: Which operating system, shell and terminal emulator (if any) are you using?

Comment: Hi, Macos Mojave zsh alacritty.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/441744/pressing-enter-produces-m-instead-of-a-newline

`stty sane` command resolves the issue for me but only temporary because the programs themselves seem to cause the problem.